# Does "spies" mean Intelligence officers?

Tags: meaning

in the Headline:

"Defense Firm Said U.S. Spies Backed Its Bid for Pegasus Spyware Maker"

source: [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/07/10/us/politics/defense-firm-said-us-spies-backed-its-bid-for-pegasus-spyware-maker.html)

seems to me U.S. Spies are same as Intelligence officers. Is that so?

Comment: Your citation is behind a paywall, but I suspect that the story says that U.S intelligence agencies supported the bid.

Comment: Considering the subhead says "The American contractor L3 Harris is said to have cited support from **intelligence officials** for its effort to acquire NSO, the Israeli spyware company blacklisted by the Biden administration.", I would say YES.

Comment: @JeffMorrow when I click the link, I see the head and sub head, even though I do not have an NYT subscription.

Comment: _Intelligence officers_ would mean military officers; _intelligence officials_ could mean civilians and not military. In some places the difference may be small.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the noun "spy" is commonly understood to mean "intelligence agents".

Comment: I was puzzled to see your answer downvoted, and promptly upvoted it. Seems to me to answer the question exactly.

Comment: @RonaldSole Sometimes people downvote "good" answers to "bad" questions. I have seen this a lot on ELL. I can see why someone might have thought answers like this one encourage people to not bother researching, or, in this case, reading what they are looking at.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't seem correct. A "spy" is more specific than an "intelligence officer," right? In common use, I think of a "spy" as someone who has personally infiltrated the country or group being spied on and directly collects information. Whereas employees of the intelligence agency who don't do this task would be, more generally, intelligence officers.

Comment: @cruthers Wellll ... one could quibble. I've heard the director of the CIA referred to in news reports as "America's chief spy". I've taken that hesitantly for exactly the reason you say: He's not really a "spy" how I understand the word, but a boss over the spies. Like I wouldn't call the owner of a trucking company the "chief truck driver" if he doesn't actually drive a truck himself. On the other hand, what about someone who works in his own country, decoding and analyzing intercepted messages from an enemy? I might not call him a spy but I wouldn't be taken aback if someone else did.